# How to scale and rotate a sprite between two points based on distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in unity and I have a small circle that shows how much power will be applied to a ball and an arrow that shows the direction.

The circle and arrow are meant to scale up to a max distance; the arrow scales but it is too big (takes up half the screen) and doesn't rotate properly; the circle does not scale at all. I have tried to change the local scale of the arrow and messed around with the various values but I am not sure what to really do. The arrow tends to only face the correct direction when the cursor is in the top left and the arrow is in the bottom right.

The two points, point A and B are two empty objects; point B is attached to the ball and pointA follows the mouse. When the ball is clicked on and the cursor is dragged away pointB moves in the opposite direction; I am trying to get the arrow to face pointB at all times or point at pointB from the opposite side of the ball.

Everything except for the arrow and circle rotating and scaling works. I'm fairly new to code and don't understand Mathf.Log. The arrow rotate and scale code is commented out as I am currently trying to get the circle to work.

If you can point me in the right direction or help with just one of these issues I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
public class PlayerBallHit : MonoBehaviour
{

    private GameObject mousePointA;
    private GameObject mousePointB;
    private GameObject arrow;
    private GameObject circle;

    // calc distance
    private float currDistance;
    public float maxDistance = 3f;

    private float spaceLimit;
    private float shootPower;
    public float shootPowervar;

    public Vector2 shootDirection;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Awake()
    {
        mousePointA = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PointA");
        mousePointB = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PointB");
        arrow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Stick");
        circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Circle");
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        currDistance = Vector2.Distance(mousePointA.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (currDistance <= 3f)
        {
            spaceLimit = currDistance;
        }
        else
        {
            spaceLimit = maxDistance;
        }

        // Direction of Hit and Circle

        StrDirMarkers();

        // calc Power & Direction

        shootPower = Mathf.Abs(spaceLimit) * shootPowervar;

        Vector3 dimxy = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;
        float difference = dimxy.magnitude;

        mousePointB.transform.position = (Vector3)transform.position + ((dimxy / difference) * currDistance * -1);
        mousePointB.transform.position = new UnityEngine.Vector3(mousePointB.transform.position.x, mousePointB.transform.position.y);

        shootDirection = (Vector2)Vector3.Normalize(mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position);
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        //arrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled =false;
        circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

        Vector2 push = shootDirection * shootPower *-1;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(push, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void StrDirMarkers()
    {
        //arrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        circle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;

        // calc position

        /*
        if (currDistance <= maxDistance)
        {
            arrow.transform.position = new Vector2((2f * transform.position.x) - mousePointA.transform.position.x, (2f * transform.position.y) - mousePointA.transform.position.y);
        }
        else
        {
            Vector2 dimxy = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;
            float difference = dimxy.magnitude;
            arrow.transform.position = (Vector2)transform.position + ((dimxy / difference) * maxDistance * -1);
            arrow.transform.position = new UnityEngine.Vector2(arrow.transform.position.x, arrow.transform.position.y);
        }
        */

        circle.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 0.04f);

        Vector3 dir = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;

        float rot; 

        if(Vector3.Angle(dir, transform.forward)> 90)
        {
            rot = Vector3.Angle(dir, transform.right);
        }else
        {
            rot = Vector3.Angle(dir, transform.right) * -1;
        }

        //arrow.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rot);

        // scale arrow

        float scaleX = Mathf.Log(1 + spaceLimit / 10000f, 2f) * 0.05f;
        float scaleY = Mathf.Log(1 + spaceLimit / 10000f, 2f) * 0.05f;

        //arrow.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 + scaleX, 1 + scaleY, 0.001f);
        circle.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 + scaleX, 1 + scaleY, 0.001f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code for scaling and rotate the arrow

```
  Vector3 dir = mousePointA.transform.position - transform.position;

    float rot;

    if (mousePointA.transform.position.y >= transform.position.y)
    {
        rot = Vector3.Angle(dir, transform.position) * -1;
    }
    else
    {
        rot = Vector3.Angle(dir, transform.position);
    }

    arrow.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rot);

    // scale arrow
    float scaleValue = Vector3.Distance(mousePointA.transform.position, 
    transform.position);
    arrow.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 + scaleValue, 
    arrow.transform.localScale.y, 1);
    circle.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 + scaleValue * 0.05f, 1 + scaleValue * 
     0.05f, 0.001f);
```

Comment: This sort of solves the scaling issue but the circle doesn't scale from the center of the ball and it also doesn't stop scaling; thanks for the push in the right direction though. The main issue is the arrow, it scales along the x axis and doesn't rotate, it could be an issue with the sprite and other code but once again thank you